# Sorting arrays - least steps

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

I wonder what is the best algorithm to sort binary array with least swaps? (having array eg [0,0,0,1,0,1,0] to become [0,0,0,0,0,1,1]).

I implemented some bubble sorts but wonder what is the optimisation for those?

My code is in python, but any language is welcomed, if anyone has a solution for the least swaps that would really improve my program and i would really appreciate!!

Comment: What type of swaps are you referring to?

Comment: You could have a look at [Sort a binary array using one traversal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-binary-array-using-one-traversal/). That has complexity O(n).

Comment: @Unmitigated swapping any element array[n] with array[n2].

Comment: @Unmitigated in the example, swapping array[4] and array[3] would be considered one swap. I am wondering what is the most efficient sorting for number of those operations

Comment: In the example, you need only one swap: `array[3] <--> array[6]`. Notice that `array[3]` is the first 1 in the array, and `array[6]` is the last 0 in the array. After the swap, the first 1 in the array is *after* the last 0 in the array, so you're done. This suggests a simple algorithm using two indexes. One index `A` starts at the beginning of the array, and is incremented until a 1 is located. The other index `B` starts at the end of the array, and is decremented until a 0 is located. If `A >= B` the algorithm is finished, otherwise `array[A]` is swapped with `array[B]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it using swaps, you can start from both ends and swap the 1s you find on the left side going forward with the 0s you find on the right side going backward.

```
A       = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0]
left1s  = (i for i,b in enumerate(A) if b==1)
right0s = (len(A)-j for j,b in enumerate(reversed(A),1) if b==0)
swapCount = 0
for i,j in zip(left1s,right0s):
    if i>=j:break
    A[i],A[j] = A[j],A[i]
    swapCount += 1
    
print(A)                 # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
print(swapCount,"swaps") # 1 swaps
```

Note that the same logic can be written without the use of iterators and zip:

```
A     = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0]
swaps = 0
f,b   = 0,len(A)-1                            # forward and backward indexes
while f<b:                                    # until forward meets backward 
    if   A[f]==0: f += 1                      # skip 0s forward
    elif A[b]==1: b -= 1                      # skip 1s backward
    else: swaps,A[f],A[b] = swaps+1,A[b],A[f] # swap misplaced bits

print(A)             # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
print(swaps,"swaps") # 1 swaps
```

Comment: I think that's the most elegant and clever solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Many languages have their own implementation.

Example for javascript:

```
[0,0,0,1,0,1,0].sort();
```

returns

```
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ]
```

Edited: adding my own implementation on javascript.

The strategy was navigate from the begin and stop when found 1, and then navigate from the end to found 0 to swap.

It's one of multiple possible implementations.

```
function sortBinaryArray(binArr){
    let i = 0;
    let j = binArr.length;
    let swapCount = 0;
    while(i < j){
        if(binArr[i] === 0) {
            // found 0 on  position i. Its sorted until now.
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        // Found 1 on posittion i. Search from the end for 0 to swap
        j--;
        while(i < j){
            if (binArr[j] === 0) {
                // Found position to swap
                binArr[i] = 0;
                binArr[j] = 1;
                i++;
                swapCount++;
                break;
            }
            j--
        }
    }
    console.log('swapCount='+swapCount);
}

var myArr = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0];
sortBinaryArray(myArr);
console.log(myArr)
```

output:

```
swapCount=1
Array(7) [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ]
```

Comment: that is an assignment though so I'd have to develop a custom algorithm :) thanks though

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `.sort()` or similar stuff I can think of that solution:

```py
arr = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0]
print([0] * arr.count(0) + [1] * arr.count(1))
```

Which ends up in `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]`

Edit:

```py
l = len(arr)
z = arr.count(0)
print([0]*z + [1] * (l - z))
```

seems to be faster with `timeit.timeit`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort a binary array, especially with python's small integer interning.

The count of ones is given by

```
ones = sum(lst)
```

The count of zeros is the length minutes that:

```
zeros = len(lst) - ones
```

You can construct the right list with

```
[0] * zeros + [1] * ones
```